# request error, status : 0 pop up with a4j:support

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam, ajax4jsf

I am encountering a pop up window with error message "Request error, status :0" when onclick event is triggered by a4j:support inside an h:commandButton.

```
    <h:commandButton id="btn1" action="#{beanA.method1}">

          <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{beanB.method1}" reRender="somePanelGrid" />

    </h:commandButton>
```

I also tried using a4j:jsFunction for beanB.method1 and use the onclick attribute of the h:commandButton but the error keeps showing on pop up/alert box. Removing the a4j:support removes the error; however, i still need to execute the beanB.method1 when the commandButton is clicked. What can be the cause of this error? Is there an alternate or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you send multiple request to server-side in the same time when you click, I would rather invoke `beanB.method1()` in `beanA.method1()`, or delay one of the action to `oncomplete` stage to get around this issue:

```
   <a4j:jsFunction name="function1" action="#{beanB.method1}" reRender="somePanelGrid" />
   <h:commandButton id="btn1" action="#{beanA.method1}" oncomplete="function1()" />
```